# Dict of Dict Sum Similar Keys with only dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I have searched around for possible answers for this, and could not find a way to do this with just dict comprehension or a form of functional programming with a dict of dicts **without using for loops**.

I have a function:

```
get_grades(theDict, hw)
```

which takes a dict of dicts and a string such as 'hw1', or 'hw4' in that type of format.

The format of theDict is:

```
get_grades({'Ggg':{'hw1': 1, 'hw2': 2, 'hw3': 3},'Hhh':{'hw1': 4, 'hw2': 3,'hw3': 6}},'hw1')
```

I am trying to take all the keys that match hw and sum all the values for that key. If hw = hw1 then the function would return:

```
5
```

(which is all the hw1 key values added together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what you mean "without using for loops"... What is the point and how would that be possible, since summing and indefinite set of items requires iteration.

I would use `sum()` in conjunction with a generator expression:

```
def get_grades(theDict, hw):
    return sum(v.get(hw, 0) for v in theDict.values())
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been struggling with this, and this answer is so simple to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
def get_grades(d, h):
  return sum(map(lambda x:x.get(h, 0), d.values()))

print(get_grades({'Ggg':{'hw1': 1, 'hw2': 2, 'hw3': 3},'Hhh':{'hw1': 4, 'hw2': 3,'hw3': 6}},'hw1'))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `sum(x.get(h, 0) for x in d.values()))`? I get user doesn't want `for` loops, but using `map` + `lambda` to avoid `for` doesn't seem right either.

Comment: @jpp True, however, the OP did specify a more functional approach. A predefined function could be created to replace `lambda` (and actually improving the efficiency level), however, `lambda` is shorter in this case.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `map`'s function arg is a `lambda` or `def` function. Either way, it's still an extra level of Python function call, so it's going to be slower than the gen exp suggested by jpp & fferri. It would be OK to use `map` if the function arg is a function that runs at C speed, though.